# If the vector space of all real valued continuous functions on the metric space (X,d) is finite dimensional then X is finite set

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, metric-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space such that $C(X,R)$ is a finite dimensional real vector space, would any one help me to show that $X$ is finite set? $C(X,R)$ denotes the set of all real valued continuous function on $X$.

Comment: For each $x\in X$, the evaluation map $\operatorname{ev}_x \colon f \mapsto f(x)$ is in $C(X,\mathbb{R})^\ast$. Show that these maps are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is infinite, let us show $\dim C(X,\mathbb{R}) \geqslant n$ for any $n$.

Pick $n$ points $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. We have the product of evaluation maps $ev: C(X, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Let's show this is surjective. But indeed, it suffices to find a function which is nonzero at $x_1$ and 0 at $x_2, \ldots, x_n$.

We may take $$y \mapsto \prod_{i \geqslant 2} d(y, x_i)$$where $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the distance function on $X$.

Comment: First, I think you meant "infinite" in your fourth word above; second, I've no idea what your last line means...

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you for the suggestions - I certainly meant infinite, and I've rewritten the last line